# MSBuild fails to build when compiling C# project referencing C++/CLI DLL in x86

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I am using VS2010 and .NET 4.0.

I have two little projects **A** and **B**. **A** is a C++/CLI DLL Project, and **B** is a C# EXE project referencing **A**. Both must be compiled in x86, because **A** uses x86 native dll.

When I build **B** with VS2010 IDE, **B** compiles well. Next I try to build **B** with MSBuild with following command line

> MSBuild B.csproj /property:Platform=x86;Configuration=Release

And it fails with following error.

> "**A**.vcxproj" (default target) (16) -> (InvalidPlatformError target) ->
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.InvalidPlatform.Targets(23,7):
>   error MSB8007: The Platform for project '**A**.vcxproj' is invalid.  Platform='x86'.
>   You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without
>   a solution file, and have specified a non-default Platform that doesn't exist for this project. [**A**.vcxproj]

It seems to happen because C++/CLI uses "Win32" as platform name, whereas C# uses "x86". So when I specify "x86", It fails to build **A**. If "Win32", fails to build **B**.

I have to use MSBuild because of auto building. Default platform for **B** is fixed to AnyCPU (and I cannot change it), so I cannot use default platform trick and must specify "x86" when building with MSBuild. How can I do this? Is there any way to change the platform name, or, the better way to use MSBuild? Can I do this without using default platform?

Comment: The platform name for a C# project is meaningless, you can name it anything you like.  Only the Platform Target setting matters.  If you cannot change a meaningless name then that's where it kinda ends.  But you really do have to explain why building project B also gets project A built.  That can only happen when you build a solution, not when you build a project.

Comment: @HansPassant Because project B references project A. That information is included in .csproj file, so MSBuild tries to build A first. And I really cannot find where I can change platform name for a C# project.. except for editing .csproj file directly, which might have some potential problems or side effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a solution for containing both projects and set it up properly, you should be able to build that solution using msbuild (afaik the solution will first build A using Win32 and then B using x86).

Another option is instead of referencing project A from B, you should just add a reference A's output dll. For that to work, first make sure A.dll goes in the same directory as B.exe. Then add a reference to project B by browing to the output directory and selecting A.dll. Also set 'Copy Local' to false since that's not needed then.

Comment: The second proposal seemed to be a little difficult, because output path of directly building .sln could be different from that of using msbuild. The first looked quite sensible, but I decided to use default platform trick because it was easier. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For this one I cannot see any way around it except for removing the dependency **A** has on the native x86 dll by replacing it with something which can interface with it and be compiled as "AnyCPU"( not sure what dll/s you're restricted by ). Basically my understanding is that being win32 means it can run on more processors than a x86 compiled program and so they're not compatible from MSbuild's point of view. What happens if you specify "AnyCPU" for the platform?

Comment: Mentioned x86 native dll that **A** uses is an external DLL, which is supported in x86 only. If B is built in AnyCPU and executed in x64 OS, it will be loaded as x64 and will not utilize the x86 native dll.

Comment: actually B probably won't even load sinec it won't find an x64 version of A or it's native dependency

Answer (score 0):

just found an interesting approach to this topic: extending the .csproj file with some custom XML in order to have the dependent .vcxproj built correctly.

http://troyparsons.com/blog/2012/08/fixing-csproj-builds-that-reference-vcxproj-files-using-assignprojectconfiguration-task/#comment-843

just in case the link would go dead, here is the important part. don't know why or how it works, but it did the job for me!

```
<Target Name="PrepProjectConfiguration" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild" Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x86'">
   <AssignProjectConfiguration
         CurrentProjectConfiguration="$(Configuration)"
         CurrentProjectPlatform="$(Platform)"
         ProjectReferences="@(ProjectReference)"
         ResolveConfigurationPlatformUsingMappings="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="AssignedProjects" ItemName="ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration" />
   </AssignProjectConfiguration>
   <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Remove="@(ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration)" />
   </ItemGroup>
   <Message Text="  regular reference %(ProjectReference.Identity)" />
   <Message Text="re-mapped reference %(ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration.Identity) - %(ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration.Configuration)|%(ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration.Platform)" />
</Target>
```